# Checking memory usage of an ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm using shared ASP.NET hosting and I have no remote-desktop access to the web server.  I only have the ability to FTP ASP.NET related files to the server.

In this scenario, how would I see how much memory my ASP.NET application is consuming?

Answer (score 1):

Could you create a page that listed various performance counters in a password-protected part of the site?  That would be my suggestion, along with making sure that somewhere on the page, a machine name or IP is listed so that should the site move among various servers, this can be noted somewhere.  Another idea would be to either write to a log file or send an e-mail with various performance counters so that you could see a history of how the server is doing, but be careful on the e-mail that this could become spam-like if you do it too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Maybe [Process.PeakVirtualMemorySize64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakvirtualmemorysize64.aspx) is more focused on your need. Did not try it myself.

Before update:
This link is about what you need.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210609140213/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041002-1.aspx